# ProGuard causing Jackson error, "Conflicting property name definitions"

Tags: android, proguard, nest-api

I am using the [Nest Android SDK](https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk) and am getting close to releasing my application. I have found that it is not possible to use Proguard with the Nest SDK as it stands today. Once a user is authenticated, the data that comes back causes the crash below.

How can I get passed this, and still keep ProGuard enabled? I created an [issue on the github page](https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk/issues/16) but I assume it will not be a high priority by Nest.

```
09-06 23:49:32.807 15229-15229/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: <my_package>, PID: 15229
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting property name definitions: 'locale' (for [field com.nestlabs.sdk.Device#b]) vs 'name' (for [method com.nestlabs.sdk.Device#b(0 params)])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.findRenamed(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.findNewName(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._renameProperties(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.client.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.nestlabs.sdk.aa.a(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.client.c.ba.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I believe we have a fix identified. Working on some updates to the SDK and we didn't seem to run into this issue in the new builds. Working on an ETA for release but I would expect sometime late September early October.

Comment: @urman thanks for the reply, great news! Were you able to reproduce it yourself before the fixes, or are you just saying you don't see it in the latest changes you are working on? If you did not reproduce, I will try to build the Nest sample app using ProGuard using the version of the Nest SDK I have and see if the issue occurs. If so, then perhaps you can do the same using your changes to see if the issue is gone.

Comment: Couldn't seem to reproduce it after some maintenance changes, but haven't explicitly tested for it on the old build. I'll double check it works before we publish and definitely let you know as soon as it goes up.

Comment: Thank you so much @urman

Comment: @urman - any update on the release ETA?

Comment: good timing! Was waiting on a service component finished today. Check now.

Comment: @urman Awesome! You made my day. Will verify that the issue is gone and let you know.

Comment: @urman unfortunately the crash is still there, even on 1.1.1. I reproduced with the Nest sample app. Let's take this conversation over to the github issue? https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk/issues/16#issuecomment-252176085